# Using A Python List or String in Dictionary Lookup?

Tags: python, json, dictionary

**Use Case**

I am making a factory type script in Python that consumes XML and based on that XML, returns information from a specific factory. I have created a file that I call FactoryMap.json that stores the mapping between the location an item can be found in XML and the appropriate factory.

**Issue**

The JSON in my mapping file looks like:

```
{

      "path": "['project']['builders']['hudson.tasks.Shell']",
      "class": "bin.classes.factories.step.ShellStep"

}
```

*path* is where the element can be found in the xml once its converted to a dict.

*class* is the corresponding path to the factory that can consume that elements information.

In order to do anything with this, I need to descend into the dictionaries structure, which would look like this if I didn't have to draw this information from a file(note the key reference = 'path' from my json'):

```
configDict={my xml config dict}
for k,v in configDict['project']['builders']['hudson.tasks.Shell'].iteritems():
    #call the appropriate factory
```

The issue is that if I look up the path value as a string or a list, I can not use it in 'iteritems'():

```
path="['project']['builders']['hudson.tasks.Shell']" #this is taken from the JSON
for k,v in configDict[path].iteritems():
    #call the appropriate factory
```

This returns a key error stating that I can't use a string as the key value. How can I used a variable as the key for that python dictionary?

Comment: Is it a requirement that the path value has such a complex syntaxe ? Or are you allowed to change it to somethinore easy to parse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `eval`:

```
eval( "configDict"+path )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `eval()` function to evaluate your path into an actual dict object vs a string.  Something like this is what I'm referring to:

```
path="['project']['builders']['hudson.tasks.Shell']" #this is taken from the JSON
d = eval("configDict%s" % path)
for k,v in d.iteritems():
#call the appropriate factory
```